# SELECT TOP 1 for each reference id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

These are my tables simplified..

```
person
( id [int],
  surname [varchar] (30),
  ref [int],
)

episode
(
  id [int],
  ref [int],
  typeId [int],
  startDate [datetime]
)

type
(
  typeId [int],
  typeName [varchar]
)
```

I want to select all the people who have more than 1 episode and the oldest episode started after 1 Jan 2013. I tried using Row_Number and partition but i'm using Sql Server 2005 and it didn't like Row_Number().

Comment: You don't show what you tried and the DB model is far from clear. Update your question if you don't want it closed within minutes...

Comment: Can you post your code where you tried Row_Number()? It should work on sql 2005:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471879/sql-server-2005-row-number

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
having count(*)>1
and min(startDate) >'1 Jan 2013'
```

Edited: Below comment is right

Comment: `min(stardate)` instead (oldest episode)

Comment: +1 now it's correct :)